# How to get In-App Product Link under the applications that are listed for your publisher account?

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I am trying to implement In-App billing in my application.For that i have created the sandbox merchant account and uploaded the apk through this account and saved the application as a draft application.To create a product list **In-App Product Link** should appear under each of the applications that are listed for your publisher account.Here is the [[link]](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_admin.html) so that one can come to know what problem i am facing.[1](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_admin.html) But this is not appearing in my case.Does anybody have any idea regarding this??[image][I have added the screen shot where the link should appear beneath the Untitled 1.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBuyr.png)

Thanks in advance,
Akash

Comment: did you check permission of your app? Documents says In-App Products link appears only if you have a Google Checkout merchant account and an application's manifest includes the *com.android.vending.BILLING* permission.

Comment: Thanks for the reply kingori.Yes I have included the permission before uploading the application and i do have the Google Check out Merchant Account.Still i am not able to get it.

Comment: did you enabled your app? I've checked my app (my app does not use in-app billing feature) and there exists in app products link. So, try enable your draft app. I think you just register new draft app, not enabled it.(right?) if you don't publish it, it will not display to others. So try to enable uploaded apk.

Comment: But i want to test the application so i uploaded it as unpublished draft application.By doing this the link doesn't appears.See this link-http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_testing.html. Its written above Table 1

Comment: unpublished and enable/disable is different thing. I think that you should enable your app still in unpublished state.

Comment: @AkashG can you get any solution becuse same issue i am facing i had already paid app upload so my merchant ac is wel recently i hd draft in app perchase application with persion but yet it's not displaying

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't appear that you have a merchant account setup. Make sure to setup your merchant account with Google Wallet/Google Checkout.

Here are instructions I found online: http://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=113468 The docs might be outdated though.

Answer (score 1):

Include the permission in your manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
```

You should have a Google Checkout account also.

Comment: Thanks for the reply sravan kumar.I have included both the permissions before uploading the application and yes i do have the Google Check out Account.Still i am not able to get it.

Comment: I have downloaded the code from this link-http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_integrate.html#billing-download. I followed all the steps given here.